# Jumping to function

Tags: python, function

I have a problem with functions. I want to know is it possible to when calling function second time program jump to that line of code, just like in assembler where would I use jmp directive. So when I firstly call decision_function after that some calc_funcs are done ( it doesn't matter what they do ), but when I call that same decision function second time I don't get execution of calc funcs.

```
def main():

    decision_function()
    calc_function1()
    calc_function2()
    calc_function3()
    decision_function(reqierment)

def decision_function(reqierment=None):

    if reqierment is None:
        do this

    else:
        do that
```

Comment: Just send it something that isn't `None`...

Comment: Sending something that isn't none will trigger some things inside decision_function but wont execute calc_functions after I call decision_function for second time....

Comment: They already won't execute a second time, unless you call `main` again.

Comment: I know that they wont, what can I do to make them execute, exept calling main function becose that does not works for me

Comment: If you _want_ the `calc_function` stuff to run every time you run `decision_function`, _put them in `decision_function`_. If you want to run them conditionally, send a flag.

Comment: I think you need to read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I guess I will do that, thank you for help.

Comment: Python isn't assembly. Trying to make it work like assembly is going to be a needlessly complicated and unpleasant experience.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer using setting a variable to true:

```
skipper = true

def main():

    decision_function()
    calc_function1()
    calc_function2()
    calc_function3()
    decision_function(reqierment)

def decision_function():

    if skipper == True:
        do this
        skipper = False

    else:
        do that
```

Comment: You'd need to have `global skipper` in `decision_function` for that to work. But really, it's better to avoid using modifiable globals.